# Runtime error on a program to make a music jukebox using Jlayer library (v1.0.1)

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, jlayer

Im trying to make an application which plays music by using a Jlayer library which has packages like:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.PlaybackEvent;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.PlaybackListener;
```

[and it has an interface which plays and stops music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHRTv.jpg)

[but it showing an error which is very confusing to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3HWe.jpg)

Any way you guys can help me out?

I tried looking through Chatgpt but to no avail. I also tried downloading newer versions of the same library.